# Get the current image name of a slickR slideshow in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, slick.js, slickr

Below is a shiny app which displays a slideshow of images with the `slickR` package. How to get the name of the current image?

```
library(shiny)
library(slickR)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$div(
      slickROutput("slickr", width="500px"),
      style = "margin-left:100px;"
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  imgs <- list.files("~/", pattern=".png", full.names = TRUE)

  output[["slickr"]] <- renderSlickR({
    slickR(imgs)
  })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Just FYI please see [this](https://github.com/yonicd/slickR/issues/53).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution with a `MutationObserver`:

```
library(shiny)
library(slickR)

js <- "
$(document).ready(function(){
  var ss = document.getElementById('slickr');
  // create an observer instance
  var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    var index = $(ss).find('.slick-current').data('slick-index');
    Shiny.setInputValue('imageIndex', parseInt(index)+1);
  });
  // configuration of the observer
  var config = {subtree: true, attributes: true};
  // observe 
  observer.observe(ss, config);
})
"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(HTML(js))
  ),
  textOutput("imgName"),
  tags$hr(),
  tags$div(
      slickROutput("slickr", width="500px"),
      style = "margin-left:100px;"
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  imgs <- list.files("~/", pattern=".png", full.names = TRUE)

  output[["slickr"]] <- renderSlickR({
    slickR(imgs)
  })

  output[["imgName"]] <- renderText({
    paste0("CURRENT IMAGE: ", basename(imgs[input[["imageIndex"]]]))
  })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Another solution, simpler: replace `js` with

```
js <- "
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#slickr').on('setPosition', function(event, slick) {
    var index = slick.currentSlide + 1;
    Shiny.setInputValue('imageIndex', index);
  });
})"
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this workaround?

I am using the index of the image and get the basename of the imagelist.

```
library(shiny)
library(slickR)

jscode <- HTML("
$(document).on('shiny:connected', function(event) {
  var imagindex = 0;
  Shiny.onInputChange('slickin', imagindex);
  $(document).on('click', '.slick-arrow', function(event) {
    var imagindex = $('.slick-active')[0].attributes[1].value;
    Shiny.onInputChange('slickin', imagindex);
  });
  $(document).on('click', '.slick-dots', function(event) {
    var imagindex = $('.slick-active')[0].attributes[1].value;
    Shiny.onInputChange('slickin', imagindex);
  });
});
")

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(jscode)),
  tags$div(
    slickROutput("slickr", width="500px"),
    style = "margin-left:100px;"
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  imgs <- list.files(getwd(), pattern=".png", full.names = TRUE);

  output[["slickr"]] <- renderSlickR({
    slickR(imgs)
  })

  observe( {
    req(input$slickin)
    print(basename(imgs[as.numeric(input$slickin) + 1]))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You're solution is better, since mine only works by clicking on the arrows or the dots. Swiping the images is not detected.

Answer (score 1):

The [slickR shiny vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/slickR/vignettes/shiny.html) describes the "official" way without using custom JS:

> Observe the active slick
> The htmlwidget is observed by shiny and information can be retrieved.
>
> Using the output name you set for the `renderSlick` object in this example
> it is `output$slick_output`
> Using this you can interact server-side "on click" of the active carousel
> by accessing elements in `input$slick_output_current$`

- `.clicked`   : The index of the clicked element
- `.relative_clicked`: The relative position of the clicked element
- `.center`    : The index of the center element
- `.total`     : The total number of elements in the carousel
- `.active`    : The ID of the active carousel

---

```
library(shiny)
library(slickR)

# create some local images
if(!dir.exists("myimages")){
  dir.create("myimages")
}

imgs <- paste0("myimages/myplot", seq_len(3), ".png")

for (myPlot in myPlots) {
  png(file = myPlot, bg = "transparent")
  plot(runif(10))
  dev.off() 
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(HTML(js))
  ),
  textOutput("imgName"),
  tags$hr(),
  tags$div(
    slickROutput("slickr", width="500px"),
    style = "margin-left:100px;"
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output[["slickr"]] <- renderSlickR({
    slickR(imgs)
  })
  
  output[["imgName"]] <- renderText({
    paste0("CURRENT IMAGE: ", basename(imgs[input$slickr_current$.center]))
  })
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution from [one of the slickR vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/slickR/vignettes/basics.html):

```
slickR(obj = nba_player_logo$uri[1:2], height = 100, width = "95%") %synch%
( slickR(nba_player_logo$name[1:2], slideType = 'p') + settings(arrows = FALSE) )
```

Worked great for me.