# Set `.center_slide` in slickR to 1 if null

Tags: r, shiny, slickr

I have a shiny app and I am using slickR. I need to access `input$slickr_current$.center` to get the current index for an image so that I can use it to create inputs based on the index. This value doesn't populate until you click the slickR slideshow. Is there a way to set the value of `input$slickr_current$.center` to 1 or activate the slideshow base on the app loading instead of clicking it?

Comment: Maybe see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56001897/1100107).

Comment: that answered my question, thank you for the link